# Spring boot logging / Java logging - Tool to show config/setup

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, slf4j, apache-commons-logging

I'm used to using log4j and whenever there were setup/config problems I'd enable "-Dlog4j.debug" and all the config info would be dumped out at startup.
This was very useful on a number of occasions.

Now I'm working on a Spring boot application, which I've found uses:

1. Commons logging Logger statements in the client code
2. A bridge jar (jcl-over-slf4j-xxx.jar) which translates the commons logging calls into slf4j [more info here](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html)
3. Finally slf4j uses "logback" as the underlying logging framework

I found it rather painful to figure all this out.
Is there an equivalent of -Dlog4j.debug which can show me how this is all hanging together at startup time?

Answer (score 1):

This is the best/only option I've found so far, and it's logback specific.
Use this -D on the command line:

```
-Dlogback.statusListenerClass=ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener
```

Taken from [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html)
This essentially is the logback equivalent of log4j's -Dlog4j.debug.
It dumps the logback startup sequence to the console at startup time, as the logging system is initialised.

This is not a true answer as I'd like some messages to show before this to show why logback is being used, but I haven't found anything like that yet.

Aside: This may also be useful for Spring Boot:

```
-Ddebug
```

Taken from [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-boot-application.html) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using logback, I assume you are using the `logback.xml` file? Then if you start that file with `<configuration debug="true">` then it should dump the status information. More information in the [documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) under *status data* section.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start, but it addresses (3) but not (1) and (2). What I'm after is something that tells me (at startup time) that my setup is as described in 1 + 2 + 3, if you see what I mean

Comment: I thought your problem was with dumping the configuration information to the console? That is what the title indicates.

Comment: Yes I want to dump all the config info to the console at startup. So I might see something like:   "logging is initialising. Commons logging is using slf4j. Slf4j is using logback. Logback is reading config file /blah/logback.xml." etc

Comment: Ah ok. I thought you wanted to dump the logback config. But probably you can find everything you want in slf4j and commons logging documentaion.